# How to add values of multiple edittexts in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am creating dynamic layout in my code. My UI has multiple rows which are dynamically created at runtime. Each row consists of single edit text. I have created single edit text object and used this object to add in multiple rows.

Lets assume that there are 5 rows so there are 5 edit texts. User can enter/delete numbers in any of the edittext. Depending on what user enters in respective edittexts, I want to update the label.The label should contain addition of all edittext values.

I am calling following function on edit text afterTextChanged callback method.

```
private void refreshTotalNumberOfDays(Editable editable){

    if(!(editable.length()==0)){
        totalDays = Integer.parseInt(editable.toString());  
    }

    finalTotalDays =totalDays+finalTotalDays;
    ftotalNumberOfDays.setText(String.valueOf(finalTotalDays));
}
```

But its not adding values correctly.

Comment: what u have tried? post some code u tried

Comment: Kindly update your question instead of adding it to comments

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to this:

```
totalDays = Integer.parseInt(editable.getText().toString());
```

It should give you the proper integer value.

To total all of them, keep an array of all the editTexts.

Make the array when you create the Activity

```
ArrayList<EditText> editTextArrayList = new ArrayList<EditText>();
editTextArrayList.add(editText1);
editTextArrayList.add(editText2);
...
```

Then on your callback Method, total them all up:

```
int total = 0;
for (EditText editText:editTextArrayList) {
    total +=  Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: problem is addition logic is only working for single digits from 0-9. If I enter two digits value then addition not working.Also I am not able to implement subtraction logic when user removes number from edittext.

Comment: Perhaps you could just grab all of the values and re-add them everytime the user changes any of the text (instead of worrying about subtracting)

Comment: I'm not sure why you are having issues with two digits.  ftotalNumberOfDays.setText(String.valueOf(finalTotalDays)); is a pretty standard piece of code

Comment: @ HalR - each time I enter something in edittext, so when i enter 12 inside one of the edittext then i m getting total as 13. 1(when 1 is enterd)+12(when 2 is entered)= 13